# Hide a data set label in multiple datasets inside android MP Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I m using two data sets to draw a line chart and circle(indicates current progress). When I try to add two datasets to the same chart, the labels are also drawn twice at the bottom of the chart.
I want to hide the **" current progress"**

```
val set1 = LineDataSet(mValues, "F1: Before Intersection Analysis")
            set1.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f)
            set1.color = Color.BLACK
            set1.lineWidth = 1f
set1.setDrawValues(false)
            set1.setDrawIcons(false)
            set1.setDrawCircles(false)
            set1.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
            set1.setDrawCircleHole(false)
set1.formLineWidth = 5f
            set1.formLineDashEffect = DashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(0f, 0f), 0f)
            set1.formSize = 15f
..
val set2 = LineDataSet(mValues, "current progress")
            set2.setDrawCircles(true)
            set2.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK)
            set2.circleRadius = 5f
            set2.color = Color.BLACK
            set2.setDrawCircleHole(false)
            //set2.setDrawValues(false)

            val dataSets: ArrayList<ILineDataSet> = ArrayList()
            dataSets.add(set1) // add the data sets
            dataSets.add(set2) // add the data sets

            // create a data object with the data sets
            val data = LineData(dataSets)
            if (binding.gaussionChart.data != null) {
                binding.gaussionChart.data.isHighlightEnabled = false
            }

            // set data
            binding.gaussionChart.data = data
            //binding.gaussionChart.legend.isEnabled = false
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution by adding the three lines of code

```
val set1 = LineDataSet(mLineData, "")
set1.formLineWidth = 0f
set1.formSize = 0f
```